# Using Countifs to count distinct values and multiple criteria?

Tags: excel, count, countif, sumifs

I am trying to count how many brands a certain client has passed through. I essentially have two columns a client list and a brand column.

In some cases, there may be duplicates of the brand so I only need to count them once.

I have tried to use several variants Countifs/Sumifs formulas but to no success.

Totally lost and would appreciate any help
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4UCu.png)

Thanks

Comment: An example of the data, expected results and what you have tried would help.

Comment: Just insert a pivot table, it will give you the correct answer in less than 15 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIFS($A:$A,$D2,$B:$B,$H$1:$H$10)>0))`

[image]

You'll need to make a helper column which contains all the brands (no duplicates). The only thing that should change in the formula is `$D2`, which is the Client in question. So it will become `$D3`, `$D4`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a formula which does not require any helper column.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($A$2:$A$13=$E2)*($B$2:$B$13<>""))/COUNTIF($B$2:$B$13,$B$2:$B$13&""))
```

The `($A$2:$A$13=$E2)` checks that the name matches.

The `($B$2:$B$13<>"")` just makes sure that any blanks are ignored (not counted as a brand).

The `COUNTIF($B$2:$B$13,$B$2:$B$13&"")` looks at unique brands only.

[image]